# Adding a DC Motor to a Simscape Model

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape, pendulum

I want simulate an inverted pendulum via Simcape. For this, i created a Model with SolidWorks and tranformed it to Simscape. So far so good. Everything worked and my Simulation shows the predicted physical Behavior.

But now i want to add a dc motor to my simulation, which is hooked to the sledge via belt.

I tried to connect the dc motor block with the revolute joint of the pulley, but it seems Matlab has some issues with it. It shows the error shown below.
Further you can see my simscape modell of my inverted pendulum and how i connectet the Dc motor block to the revolute jo

Has anybody an idea how to connect the dc motor correctly or is there somthing wrong with my simscape model?

I´m kind of running out of ideas and I´m gratefull for any help I can get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPMss.png)

Answer (score 0):

It says one of your componenet that needs to rotate, is strictly connected to the world. I believe you need yo change that.